# How can I retrieve data from two different tables?

Tags: sql

I have two tables `item` and `price`. The tables share no common column.

In the first table `Item` there is a column `weight` and the other table `Price` columns are `price`, `sizefrom` and `sizeto`.

```
Item
--------  --------
item      weight

Price
--------- -------  -----
sizeFrom  sizeTo   price
```

How can I get the price for an item (or items) with weight between sizefrom and size to... please help me out

Comment: Can you please reword with full words and punctuation? I'm having trouble interpreting.

Comment: Ask your question in Google.. Mr google will help you out ;)

Comment: I prefer asking Miss Cortana - She has the Edge on her side.

Answer (score 3):

you could do it like that

```
SELECT DISTINCT price FROM PRICE, ITEM WHERE weight BETWEEN sizeFrom AND sizeTo
```

Comment: The sad thing is we will never know if this is right. But Kudo's for trying :D